# Beta in Play-Store does not support all devices I want

Tags: android, google-play, beta

I wanted to do an update on my application in the play store. So I created a Beta APK and uploaded it into the beta-tab in the dev-console and published it.

The beta seems online now.

If I click on the button in the right upper corner to switch into the "advanced mode".

Then google tells me something with a weird translation:

```
Einige Geräte sind zur Ausführung mehrerer APKs berechtigt. In einem solchen Szenario erhält das Gerät die APK mit dem höheren Versionscode.

Die zuvor aktiven APKs unterstützten mehr Geräte als die in der Entwurfskonfiguration. Einige Geräte erhalten keine Upgrades. 

Geräte, auf denen momentan Version 10 ausgeführt wird, werden von der aktuellen Konfiguration nicht mehr unterstützt. Diese Geräte erhalten keine Upgrades. 
API-Ebenen befinden sich im Bereich 3-8 und 
Bildschirm-Layouts enthalten mindestens eines der folgenden Elemente: [small, normal, large, xlarge*] und 
Funktionen enthalten alle der Elemente [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN], jedoch keine der folgenden: [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS]

Geräte, auf denen momentan Version 7 ausgeführt wird, werden von der aktuellen Konfiguration nicht mehr unterstützt. Diese Geräte erhalten keine Upgrades. 
API-Ebenen befinden sich im Bereich 9+ und 
Bildschirm-Layouts enthalten mindestens eines der folgenden Elemente: [normal, large*, xlarge*] und 
Funktionen enthalten alle der Elemente [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN], jedoch keine der folgenden: [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS] 

oder 

API-Ebenen befinden sich im Bereich 18+ und 
Version enthalten keines der folgenden Elemente: [BETA] und 
Bildschirm-Layouts enthalten mindestens eines der folgenden Elemente: [normal, large*, xlarge*] und 
Funktionen enthalten alle der folgenden Elemente: [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN]
```

Does that look similar to someone of you? Especially the last part about API 18+. To me it sounds like that beta users with Android 4.3 do not get updates. What's the whole thing about

```
Version enthalten keines der folgenden Elemente: [BETA]
// tranlation
Versions do not contain one of the following elements: [BETA]
```

Do I have to add something new to the manifest I don't know?

Next thing is, after a couple of hours it needed until the beta version was visible and downloadable for me, it happened that a friend of mine could not download it at the same time.
We both were opt in as test users for the beta. He with his Desire HD(2.2.3) and me with Nexus 4 (4.3) as I support API 8+ we both should have been able to download the app.

Here the important part out of my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 

<supports-screens 
    android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" /> 

<application> 
...
```

Any help?

Comment: couldn't download? What was the problem exactly? Anything indicated by the Google Play app?

Comment: Everytime he wanted to download the beta app, he just got the old one. (the one published for the public)